# Softlayer: IBM Cloud: API calls to search and retrieve Account > Audit Log

Tags: api, logging, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm looking for a way to query 'Account > Audit Log' in IBM Cloud via API calls. Basically, the information that is available here https://cloud.ibm.com/account/audit-log but retrieved and searched from a script. Can anyone share a relevant example?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve Audit logs you can to use [SoftLaye_Event_Log::getAllObjects](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects/).

Below an example using a REST API call to get the logs:

```
Method: GET

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects.json?resultLimit=0,50
```

Note: The resultLimit above retrieves the last 50 events.

For events logs, it is recommended using filters to limit how far back your search for Events, otherwise you could be paging through Events for a long time.

Below an example  using a REST API call to get the logs with filter by date:

```
Method: GET 

https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Event_Log/getAllObjects.json?resultLimit=0,50&objectFilter={"eventCreateDate":{"operation":"greaterThanDate","options":[{"name":"date","value":["2020-03-16T00:00:00.0000-06:00"]}]}}&objectMask=mask[eventName,label,eventCreateDate]
```

References:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/python/event_log/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks/

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-result-limits-softlayer-api/